# Opening ".bat" file in java code

Tags: java, mysql, batch-file

I'm developing a project in **Java**. When I export the project in **.jar**, I need to start **mysqld** to run my database. I start mysqld using a .bat file which this file is needed to be opened every time user opens the main file to access to database. The batch file content is:

.\data\bin\mysqld.exe --no-defaults --console --port=3306 --collation-server=utf8_persian_ci --character-set-server=utf8 --socket=mysql.sock --basedir=.\data --datadir=.\data\data --pid-file=".\data\data\MysqldResource.pid
pause

The data folder contains database files and is placed in the same folder with .jar and .bat files.

I don't know how to open the .bat file from the Java code.

[image: The image of project folder "After Installation"]

The code of executing .bat file is written under the one of the project packages.

Please help me. 
Thanks.

Comment: I am not very clear about your question, but seems you are looking for `ProcessBuilder` to execute a `.bat` file?

Comment: Yes, but the addressing is an important problem. I can not address absolutely.

Comment: seems you are looking for a way to get the path of a running jar. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/320542/how-to-get-the-path-of-a-running-jar-file whether can help

Comment: Thanks, here is one more question. As you see in the picture, I converted .jar file to .exe. Does it have any problem? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You must use the [Runtime.exec()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec-java.lang.String-) method:

`Process batch = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c D:\\Projects\\Terminal\\project Deployment\\run_server.bat");`

Check the path for correctness; it's advisable to use an absolute path, otherwise keep in mind that the starting path is going possibly to be your user home, depending on how Java is run.

Comment: The problem is here that, I can't use an absolute path for this. This is a product. I want to address how, I don't face to problem after creating setup.

Comment: @MustafaMohammadi using an absolute path is not your problem then, it's how to find the path out: see Wilson's comment above for a way.